# Can the SSD in a Seagate Firecuda 2.5" SSHD be used a separate device?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I'm planning to buy a Seagate Firecuda 2.5" SSHD with SATA interface and insert it to my laptop running Linux. Is it possible to make Linux recognize two SATA devices (one is the SSD and one is the HDD), and use them independently? If yes, how can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible: The HD and SSD parts of the Firecuda are interwoven at the firmware level to appear as a single device to the SATA bus.

I already tried.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this could be possible, as internally this device consists of a classic harddrive and a 8 GB (or 32 GB depending on exact model) SSD like device used as cache buffer.

However, to make this hybrid solution transparent to a computer that (normally *) expects only a single device to be attached to a SATA port the firmware in these drives hides this completely from the SATA controller, presenting only a single drive.
Thus the SSD cache is completely invisible and can not be accessed directly via the SATA bus.

There is another benefit to this hiding as well: The firmware and hardware can be far less complicated (and thus more reliable and cheaper to design/manufacture) as it doesn't need to to deal with the dual-use (cache and independent SSD) situation.

*) There is such a thing as a SATA expander that allows to connect multiple SATA devices to be accessed via a single SATA port. These are quite rare and not supported by the majority of motherboards.

Comment: Elaborating on this: the SSD in the Firecuda is not connected to the SATA bus via a dedicated flash controller - it is in reallity not a separate SSD, but just flash memory directly controlled by the disk controller.

Comment: @EugenRieck I wasn't aware of the exact technical design of this particular device, but the variant as you describe is the most common. And that is exactly what I meant with "firmware and hardware can be far less complicated". It doesn't get much simpler than having the raw flash-storage directly interfaced on the disk-controller. (Having the flash on-die with the controller would be even more simple from a technical standpoint, but to my knowledge no manufacturer uses that (yet). I doubt current demand for such drives would justify the cost to develop such an all-in-one chip.)